# Script error in Webbrowser, page doesn't load

Tags: vb.net, browser, webbrowser-control

I have a form called form1 with a webbrowser called webbrowser1. I navigate to http://plus.im with the webbrowser, but the webbrowser shows a script error and the page doesn't load (only the silver background image does). I set the ScriptErrorsSuppressed property to True for webbrowser1 and the page still doesn't load (however the dialog box with the script error is suppressed).

All my code:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://plus.im/")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: `ScriptErrorSuppress` just makes the error dialogs disappear.  It doesn't do anything to the errors themselves.  Are you sure the page isn't loading, or might it just not be rendering because of unhandled (HtmlWindow.Error)[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/system.windows.forms.htmlwindow.error.aspx] events?

Answer (score 0):

Just taking a quick look at it, IM+ requires HTTPS, try that script as https://plus.im/, your browser may not support the redirect, or may fail loading HTTPS websites (certificates, etc).